# Url redirect using .htaccess from old url links to new url links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Url redirect using  .htaccess from old url links to new url links
I want to redirect the url from 
`http://www.example.net/abc/abc-post/item/123-abc-xyz` to  `https://www.example.net/abc/index.php/123-abc-xyz`.

I tried the following code  , but it is not not working in .htaccess

```
redirect 301 http://www.example.net/abc/abc-post/item/123-abc-xyz https://www.example.net/abc/index.php/123-abc-xyz.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `http://` and hostname in URI pattern. Also it is better to use `RedirectMatch` so that you can capture `123-abc-xyz` and reuse in target:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/abc-post/item/(123-abc-xyz)/?$ https://www.example.net/abc/index.php/$1
```